# C# - Member variables passed to internal methods?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

When a class has an internal variable, should it be passed to methods internally, or should the method 'know' about it?

Eg

```
int _someid;

private void MyFunction(int ID)
{ use ID ... }
```

**or**

```
private void MyFunction()
{ use _someid ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should use the second example.

If this method is meant to only use the member variable, then the second example is correct.

If your intentions are to use this method with other passed in values, from say other methods within the class, or maybe some external calls, then the first option will do.

Comment: I agree. That is what internal/private fields are for. All methods of a class gets to use all fields of a class whether private or public.

Answer (score 2):

The method should 'know' about it. This is a large part of the point of having fields in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it just depends I guess.  Do you ever want to call this method with anything but _someId as the parameter?  If so, use the first example.  If not, use the second.

Comment: This is true, but there are two cases to consider here - either the method is part of the interface, or it's part of the implementation. If it's part of the implementation, then it doesn't matter - we can refactor to add the parameter later if we need it, but for now we should just keep it simple. You Ain't Gonna Need It. If it's part of the interface, on the other hand, we have a huge problem: if it's supposed to be called with the field value some of the time, how is the calling code supposed to deal with that? Suddenly we're writing an accessor just to support some other method. Yuck.

Comment: Right, but the OP clearly states that this is a private ("internal") method.

Answer (score 0):

The member variable is scoped to the class.  So member functions 'know' about it.  So assuming your member function is not static, your second example is correct.